# Не вижу настроенного QLayout вместе с кнопкой QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("<center>Привет, мир!</center>");
    QPushButton *btnQuit = new QPushButton("&Закрыть окно");
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox->addWidget(label);
    vbox->addWidget(btnQuit);
    w.setLayout(vbox);
    QObject::connect(btnQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &a, SLOT(quit()));

     w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `w.centralWidget()->setLeyout(...);`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    w.resize(600, 600);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("<center>Привет, мир!</center>");
    QPushButton *btnQuit = new QPushButton("&Закрыть окно");
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout();
    vbox->addWidget(label);
    vbox->addWidget(btnQuit);
    w.setLayout(vbox);
    QObject::connect(btnQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &a, SLOT(quit()));

     w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Сделай на QWidget сразу, отнаследуй класс MainWindow от QWidget - это более популярный стиль в Qt.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QMainWindow window;
    QWidget widget;
    window.setCentralWidget(&widget);

    QLabel *label = new QLabel("<center>Привет, мир!</center>");
    QPushButton *btnQuit = new QPushButton("&Закрыть окно");
    QVBoxLayout *vbox = new QVBoxLayout(&widget);
    vbox->addWidget(label);
    vbox->addWidget(btnQuit);
    window.setLayout(vbox);
    QObject::connect(btnQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &a, SLOT(quit()));

     window.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Решение через QMainWindow.

Comment: Sorry, Александр, вы где-то прочитали или вам кто-то рассказал, что QWidget - это более популярный стиль в Qt.?

Comment: @S.Nick, во всем коде, что я пишу в Qt. Пользуюсь QWidget, если вам нужен QMainWindow, то ничего плохого в этом нету, потому что он наследуется от QWidget.

Все мои знакомые около 3 человек, которые используют Qt и все пишут QWidget, хотя при создании проекта создается файл с MainWindow. 

Я использование QMainWindow видел только в вопросах на стаке, а на гитхабе ни разу, если мне нужно что-то обычно пишу сам, но QMainWindow определенно удобнее будет чем QWidget. (Я не сумасшедший - QPushButton и прочие саб-айтемы от QWidget я использую, но конкретно, то что дает QMainWindow мне не нужно).

Comment: Тот же [qt-creator использует QMainWindow](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/libs/utils/appmainwindow.h). Если вам не нужны возможности QMainWindow, то почему вы считаете что автору вопроса они тоже не нужны?

Comment: @needKVAS, я очень не хочу быть грубым, но сейчас я расширю свой код, чтобы добавить, то что ему нужно, но там будет QWidget widget; так как для добавления того, что хочет вопрошающий - нужно centralWidget()

Comment: Код стайл через QObject::connect(btnQuit, SIGNAL(clicked()),
                     &a, SLOT(quit()));

тоже плохая идея, потому что иногда невидно ошибок в такой форме.

Comment: Вы дважды ставите `QVBoxLayout` на widget. `window.setLayout(vbox);` можно убрать.

Comment: @needKVAS, я не понял, можете сделать это и залить на pastebin, а сюда кинуть на него ссылку.
как мы без setLayout установим наш QVBoxLayout.

Comment: Конструктор [QVBoxLayout(QWidget *parent)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qvboxlayout.html#QVBoxLayout-1) устанавливает Layout на родительский widget. В первом примере вы его не используете, а во втором используете.